# why is a bash read prompt not appearing when a script is run?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that prompts the user for different information based on what they're trying to do. The prompts are usually done with `read -p`. Usually it works just fine, the user sees what is being asked, enters what they need to enter, and everything does what it needs to do.

See the following (sanitized) snippet of a function in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function_name() {
if [ "$this_value" == "default" ];then
    echo "Value set to default."
    read -p "Enter desired value here: " desired_value
    desired_value=${desired_value^^}
        if [ "${#desired_value}" != 3 ] ;then
            echo "$desired_value is an invalid entry."
            exit 1
        fi
        if [ "$desired_value" != "$(some command that returns something to compare against)" ];then
            echo "$desired_value is an invalid entry."
            exit 1
        fi
    read -p "You entered $desired_value. Is this correct? [y/N] " reply
    reply=${reply,,}
    case "$reply" in
        y|yes)  
            $some command that does what I want it to do
        ;;
        *)
            echo "User did not enter yes"
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac
fi
}
```

Usually the `Enter desired value here` and `is this correct?` lines appear just fine. But in a few instances I've seen, for some reason the `read` prompt is just blank. A user will see the following:

```
./script.bash
##unrelated script stuff
##unrelated script stuff
Value set to default.
user_entered_value_here

User did not enter yes. Exiting.
```

This is a real example that just happened that finally made me come here to ask what is going on (and I modified appropriately to make it an SO post).

What's happening is these two blank lines appear instead of the `read -p` text. For the first one, the user entered `user_entered_value_here` because they already know what is supposed to be entered there even without the `read` prompt. The second one, the `Y/N` prompt, they don't know, so they see it apparently hanging, and hit Enter instead of y, causing it to trigger the * case option.

I don't understand why the `read -p` text is not appearing, and especially why it's appearing for most users but not *all* users. I suspect there's some kind of environmental setting that causes this, but for the life of me I can't figure out what. This is being run only on RHEL 6.2, under bash 4.1.2.

Comment: read prompt `-p` option is a Bash-only feature. Some of your users may have different shell like zsh, ksh or even dash.

Comment: @LéaGris If all users run the script like indicated by OP this should not matter, the script contains the bash shebang line.

Comment: I thought of this actually, but as far as I can see it isn't the problem. My users all use bash as far as I know and as far as they've admitted, but for user whose output is the basis of the example I gave above I asked them exactly how it was launched. They ran it as "/absolute/path/script.bash" and checking their current shell (`echo $SHELL`) returns /bin/bash. and line 1 of the script is `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @Kefka Have you looked into FD redirections, either somewhere in your script (e.g. some `exec` statement or around the function call)? If stderr is redirected in some cases when `read` is called, the prompt will not be displayed, but other output may still be there.

Comment: @MichaelJaros I just checked through the script. Redirects are not used anywhere in relation to this function, and `exec` is unused altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the man of bash to catch some kind of detail about the `read` built-in. It is specified that `-p` option displays the "prompt **on standard error**, without a trailing newline, before attempting to read any input.  **The prompt is displayed only if input is coming from a terminal**".

Let's consider the simple script `input.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Prompt : " value
echo The user entered:  "$value"
```

Example of execution:

```
$ ./input.sh
Prompt : foo
The user entered: foo
```

1. If stderr is redirected:

```
$ ./input.sh 2>/dev/null
foo
The user entered: foo
```

2. If the input is a pipe

```
$ echo foo | ./input.sh
The user entered: foo
```

3. If the input is a heredoc

```
$ ./input.sh <<EOF
> foo
> EOF
The user entered: foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote your script with shell agnostic grammar and fixed some errors like comparing the string length with a string comparator `!=` `=` rather than a numerical comparator `-ne` `-eq`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

this_value=default

toupper() {
  echo "$1" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
}

function_name() {
  if [ "$this_value" = "default" ]; then
    echo "Value set to default."
    printf "Enter desired value here: "
    read -r desired_value
    desired_value=$(toupper "$desired_value")
    if [ "${#desired_value}" -ne 3 ]; then
      printf '%s is an invalid entry.\n' "$desired_value"
      exit 1
    fi
    if [ "$desired_value" != "$(
      echo ABC
      : some command that returns something to compare against
    )" ]; then
      echo "$desired_value is an invalid entry."
      exit 1
    fi
    printf 'You entered %s. Is this correct? [y/N] ' "$desired_value"
    read -r reply
    reply=$(toupper "$reply")
    case $reply in
      'y' | 'yes')
        : "Some command that does what I want it to do"
        ;;
      *)
        echo "User did not enter yes"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  fi
}

function_name
```